# Jquery UI droppable behavior on Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, jquery-ui-droppable

Can someone shed some light into why the following minimally simple test behaves differently on IE compared to Chrome and FF?

Specifically, on IE the red "Drop Here" box moves when the yellow box is dropped on it.

(Strangely, this snippet seems to work as expected when I ask IE to emulate IE 7 but the odd behavior shows up on IE 8, 9 and 10)

http://jsfiddle.net/zuilserip/8w47sc39/

Any thoughts why? Any workarounds to get consistent behavior?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .DropBox {
                float: left;
                width: 75%;
                line-height: 70px;
                text-align: center;
                background-color: yellow;
            }

            .TargetBox {
                margin-left: 80%;
                width: 20%;
                line-height: 70px;
                text-align: center;
                background-color: red;
            }
        </style>

        <script>
            $(function () {
                $(".DropBox").draggable({revert: "invalid" });
                $(".TargetBox").droppable({
                    drop: function (event, ui){
                        $(ui.helper).hide("highlight",2000);}
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="DropBox">Drop Me</div>
        <div class="TargetBox">Drop Here</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I executed your code in JsFiddle in IE11 and as expected it did not work. The Dropbox was not draggable.

I went ahead and made some changes myself in JsFiddle. Fortunately, I was able to make it work in both IE11 and Firefox:

http://jsfiddle.net/8w47sc39/4/

```
$(function () {
    $(".DropBox").draggable({
        revert: false
    });
    $(".TargetBox").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $(ui.helper).hide("highlight", 2000);
        }
    });
});
```

Below is the summary of the changes:

1. I changed the revert property of draggable to "true" - just so it has a definite Boolean value
2. In the Framework and Extensions dropdown I chose "No Library (Pure JS)"
3. In the External Resources tab I added the ffg:

   - http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js
   - http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js

These resources are basically the references from the draggable sample in the JQuery site:

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#default

Comment: Thank you Roman, your edits definitely fixed some issues. Though the initial issue I had, remains. Even with in your code. 

Specifically, if you run the code on IE the "Drop Here" box shifts to the right for the 2 seconds it takes for the "Drop Me" box to fade. This does not happen in either Chrome of FF.